# Push from UIViewcontroller to a new instance of the same UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I use storyboard. And I have a `UIViewcontroller` with a button. When I press this button I need to make a new instance of the same `UIViewcontroller`, and pass some data from the first view to the next.

This is a view in embedded in a navigation controller.

I have setup the segue from the button to the view itself. And it works kind of...

But I miss some buttons in the navigation title area, and get a warning from Xcode

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
```

and

```
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

What is the best/correct way of doing this? When the user fill the view with data, and press the button, the same view will appear and the user can fill in some more data. This loop can go on multiple times before the user tap "Send", and all the data will be sent to another `UIViewcontroller`.

Comment: I am curious why you are choosing to do it this way rather than "updating" the current view. Your described method doesn't seem to offer a benefit that I can pinpoint.

Comment: Nothing would have pleased me more than do this an easier way. Though maybe this was one "fancy" way of doing it.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're pushing the new instance of the same `UIViewController`?

Comment: I can. But first I will try to do it with a simple refresh of the view. If that does not succeed I will come back.  Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: I recently had a bug on not being able to connect a segue to the same view controller in a StoryBoard, apple sent me a reply and image showing it works mostly (but not for UITableViewControllers :-( ) - so conceptually it should work, and Apple sanctions the practice.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by presenting a new instance of the current VC? If you explain more about what you are trying to make happen in the transition I try to point you into an easier way than your current thought process.